Two Runner in single .xcworkspace file
I'm stuck in this situation where I can see two runner in my workspace. I don’t know how this happened.
Is there anyone facing the same problem or can anyone solve this problem then it would be beneficial for me.
I'm a beginner level developer in Flutter


perhaps you accidentally added two references, check two Runners's paths then remove one


